# Export DataGridView to XML - C#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in my application with values from a database table. I also have functions that filter the data in the gridview.

I want to know if its possible to save the filtered data in the gridview in an XML file.

How would I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: if the data grid is bound to a datatable, you could make sure they are synced and then save the datatable in XML with the `WriteXml()` method

Comment: the data gird is bound to a dataset. When I try to use Dataset.WrtiteXML(filepath), the hole dataset saves to the xml file and not the filtered one. How can I sync my dataset to a datatable?

Comment: Hmm how are you filtering your grid?

Comment: I use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx to filter my gridview.

Comment: Eny idea how could save my filtered data?

Comment: You might have to go manual and read/loop the gridview into a datatable and then save that into xml.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried [DataTable.WriteXml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: My datagrid is bound to a dataset. When I use Dataset.WriteXML() the hole dataset saves to the file and only the filted data, wich is what I want :S

Comment: I've a DataGridView such that it is not bound to any DataSet and My application just populates the DataGrid at the BackEnd. How do I export this DataGrid to XML?? Can you pls help?

Answer (score 0):

If your datatables datasource is a `DataTable` then

```
table.DefaultView
```

contains a subset of your data that reflects the current sorting / filtering

```
var table = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
var view = table.DefaultView;
```

this view can be saved as XML, too

```
view.ToTable().WriteXml(@"c:\view.xml");
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that your datagridview is using datatable as the source? It looks like you are using some different object such as dataset as source. 
Try

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds = (DataSet)datagridview.DataSource;

ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(xml_file, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);

Comment: You are creating an unnecessary (unused) object at your first line